# Cannot clone Git repository into sourcetree, Login screen keeps appearing

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

In BitBucket, when I select clone into source tree, the URL is of format

Sourcetree opens with details to clone, but keeps asking for my login details no matter how many times I enter them.

```
https://myname@bitbucket.org/mygroup/myrepository.git
```

I have no problems on a different computer ( also Windows 10 )

I have tried upgrading SourceTree  and Reinstalling Source Tree

I have tried System Git and Embedded Git and reinstalling both Git

I can clone Mercurial repositories

At the Dos prompt I can type

```
git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/mygroup/myrepository.git
```

I get a message

```
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered
An error occurred wihe sending the request
```

then it asks for my password
then it proceeds with the clone

However in sourcetree the repository shows that there are more branches to pull.
I am unable to pull these branches

When I go to the Tools->Options->Authentication tab I can see myname@bitbucket.org as an Account.

If I try to add myname@mydomain.com.au I get

Authentication failed
Invalid URL: The hostname could not be parsed.

Comment: looking at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-keeps-asking-for-login-and-password/qaq-p/146765

Comment: looking at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Getting-quot-fatal-Authentication-failed-for-quot-error/qaq-p/624663

Comment: The problem just re-appeared on my windows 7 computer. It seemed I needed to upgrade as well as remove the password file.

Comment: Also I went into tools->options->authentication and refreshed the password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Atlassian community](http://From%20https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Getting-quot-fatal-Authentication-failed-for-quot-error/qaq-p/624663)

"The only thing that worked for me was navigating to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree and removing the passwd file."

Comment: You saved my day. Thx, Win 10, st ver 3.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem , but on MacOS. Just for completion of the answer I will add that on MacOS the passwords are stored in the KeyChain Access and they need to be deleted from there.